# How to add one hour in django {% now %} template tag?

Tags: django, datetime, django-template-filters

I want to add one hour in current time using django {% now %} tag? How can i do it.

{% now 'h:i A' %}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the view with datetime.timedelta() and then pass the variable to the template.

```
    def view(request):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        return render(request, "template.html", {'time': time })
```

And in the template `{{ time }}`

Comment: You need also - import datetime

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with the built-in TemplateTag `now` alone.

You need either a custom template-tag or at least a custom filter to do this (see [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)), e.g.

```
{% now 'h:i A' as my_time %}
{{ my_time|addhour }}
```